# Banach algebras for which left invertible implies invertible

Tags: banach-algebras

Are there noncommutative Banach algebras in which left invertibility implies invertibility? If so, what are they called?

Comment: How about matrix algebras? Every Banach algebra with topological stable rank 1 has this property: 

M.A. Rieffel, Dimension and stable rank in the K-theory of C*-algebras, Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 46 (1983), 301–333. (Proposition 3.1).

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. Will check and update comment again if it does what I hope it does

Comment: Tomasz avoided autopromotion, but [his paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08608.pdf) with S. Draga is relevant (+1 to both).

Comment: Usually the terms Dedekind finite or von Neumann finite are used